# Html input button with two lines in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, button

I trying to make a button that has two lines. I am using the following html

```
<input type="button" value="line1&#10;line2"/>
```

But in IE, I'm getting the following

[image]

Is there a way to fix the alignment using html or css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `button` element. You will have less problems as anything can be placed within it.